# BadImageFormatException: Attempting to use a C++ DLL file in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, x86

Win32 C++ DLL project is saved in my bin/Debug file with the other DLLs.

Running Debug x86 mode on my C# project.

From previous attempts to solve this problem I have changed the Build Configuration to x86 from x64 but I still receive the same error.

```
namespace ComputerToArduino
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {

        [DllImport("MySimpleLib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int AddNumber(int a, int b);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            disableControlsArduino();
            disableControlsMotor();
            getAvailableComPorts();
            chartInit();

            int result = AddNumber(1, 2);
            Console.Write(result);
        }
    }
}
```

I created a DLL project in Visual studio. This is my main DLL code:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int AddNumber(int n1, int n2);


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int AddNumber(int n1, int n2)
{

    return n1 + n2;

}
```

I am receiving this error message which I do not understand:

> Exception thrown: 'System.BadImageFormatException' in ComputerToArduino.exe
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in ComputerToArduino.exe
>   An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
>
> 'ComputerToArduino.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ComputerToArduino.exe): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\Runtime\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   The program '[14748] ComputerToArduino.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Error after adding extern to C++ function:

Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' : 'A call to PInvoke function 'ComputerToArduino!ComputerToArduino.Form1::AddNumber' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.'

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question with results of your investigations based on similar `BadImageFormatException` posts?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Added. Following this post I changed the Platform target to x86 but I am still getting the same issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183232/error-an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-badimageformatexception-occurred

Comment: Are you compiling the DLL as 32 or 64 bit?   If the dll is c++ then it's likely that AddNumber is being mangled, you should add extern "C" {}.

Comment: @Neil I believe 32. I am just using the default DLL project in Visual Studio so I believe 32 bit. I got a PInvoke error after adding the extern "C". I really don't know what's going on.

Comment: In x86 (in contrast to x64), there are different calling conventions. I believe the language C (and extern "C") defaults to the `__cdecl` calling convention. You may want to try [`__stdcall`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=vs-2019) instead, like this: `extern "C" __stdcall __declspec(dllexport) int AddNumber(int n1, int n2);`

Comment: @AndreasWenzel When I copy that line in, it throws an error and says expected an identifier under the int.

Comment: Try the following instead: `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall AddNumber(int n1, int n2);` Do you get the same error then?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel it threw an error until I added __stdcall to the actual function as well. Now in my C# code there is an error on this line:         DllImport("MySimpleLib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]. It is saying identifier expected.

Comment: You didn't write "__stdcall" into the C# code, did you? That should only go into the C++ code. The C# code is still exactly the same as what you posted in your question, isn't it?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yeah, nothing on my C# code was touched. I added the __stdcall to the line that has the extern "C" and in the line where I create the AddNumber function. I updated my code to what it looks like now above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206813/discussion-between-andreas-wenzel-and-colinodowd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In x86 (in contrast to x64), there are different calling conventions. The language C (and `extern "C"` in C++) defaults to the [cdecl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cdecl?view=vs-2019) calling convention, whereas C# defaults to the [stdcall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=vs-2019) calling convention. Therefore, you must set the calling convention to cdecl in C#, like this:

```
[DllImport("MySimpleLib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int AddNumber(int a, int b);
```